# How can I speed up Gradle dependency resolution or generally improve performance?

Tags: groovy, gradle, configuration, parallel-processing

I'm converting a very large build over from Maven.  There were a number of BOMs which I've converted to dependency lists. I'm also using the Spring Dependency management plug-in.

Problem is that dependency management is taking forever. Note that it seems to take way too long even when I use `--offline`. I've also just read that using `allprojects {}` and `subprojects{}` causes parallelism to fail. Clearly I need something that provides similar functionality, though. The objective of this migration in the first place was to improve performance but I don't think it's any better so far. I need to know:

How can I set up my dependency lists in configuration phase, do it only once and have it scoped so that the information is available to all projects? Is there an example of a plug-in that does this? Of course, it would have to work with parallelism.

Is there anything I need to do with the Spring dependency management plugin that will improve performance?

Right now, build time is roughly 25 minutes (running offline) and I'm on a half-way decent 8 core box. That's with the daemon running and no unit or integration testing. :-/

Comment: This should be only happening on the first build on a box, right? Damn you must have a ton of dependencies though.

Comment: I just moved the lists to an ext block outside of allprojects / subprojects.

Comment: Actually I've been doing a clean first so maybe that makes the daemon reload everything? Moving to ext block actually lost me a second rather than being an improvement.

Comment: Every time I try to run it in parallel I get an xjc error regarding xom (com.sun.xml.xsom.*).

Comment: OK so if I do clean, but the source files are the same, it re-builds everything? Should it do that? Seems pointless.

Comment: Of course it does, you've thrown all the class files away

Comment: OK but I just ran a build with no clean and no changes and it was 21 minutes. Not much improvement. If nothing changes shouldn't it be a lot quicker? Wait... that was parallel too. Cmd was: "time gradle build -x test -x integrationTest --offline --parallel"

Comment: Run it with `--profile` and look at the report in `build/reports/profile`

Comment: Think you're going to have to show your build.gradle file(s) (or a similar example) so we can see if there's anything glaringly wrong

Comment: Also, what os/jdk are you on?

Comment: [Link to the docs about the profile flag](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:profiling_build)

Comment: Profile. That's a good idea. I'll try that. Linux Mint / Java 8

Comment: Even building the drools stuff, maven does this is 6 minutes. :-( I didn't really see anything interesting in profile other than that configuration was zipping by really fast (0.621s) and execution took 13 minutes.  Clearly though the bottle neck is dependency resolution which took 29 minutes. I have a theory. MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g" How can I set this for Gradle?

Comment: How many dependencies do you have?  all from maven central?  are they getting cached ok in ~/.m2?  I'm stumped without seeing the code...maybe asking [over on the gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/c/help-discuss) might get another idea?

Comment: Also, what version of gradle? And have you tried with `--daemon`? That should speed up the second run

Comment: Of course cached in ~/.m2, either by Gradle or Maven. Problem with this sort of thing is that redacting a build of this size for online assisted troubleshooting is quite a lot of work. I would LOVE to get your help but I also like working here. Even so, I'll check to see what I have for options. I might be able to get some slack because I am the only Gradle guy here so far.

Comment: Right now I'm looking into using the gradle wrapper to set the options.

Comment: Plot thickens: 
https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2193

Comment: "allprojects {} and subprojects{} causes parallelism to fail" This is not true. I use both in a project with over 750 subproject and 3m+ loc. Our full clean build time is under 15 minutes.

Comment: Are you using Ant XJC and Apache CXF JavaExec tasks?

Comment: What type of drive to you have? We don't have SSDs.

Comment: Also it says right in the docs that using allprojects{} and subprojects{} causes coupling which sabotages parallelism. See 24.9. Decoupled Projects HOWEVER note that clarification here http://bit.ly/1SHUuh6 Where it mentions you have to do it in configuration time. IDK what they mean by that though since it should have been in config time anyway.

Comment: Admittedly that stuff is pretty old. An update would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing more about your environment or your set up. But some general rules:

1. Are you sure it is the dependency resolution that is the problem, use --profile to get more information. ([see docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:profiling_build))
2. Make sure you only have one repository to look from, preferably close to you and fast. We normally set up a proxy in our Nexus, that way we let Nexus cache for the whole department. For each new repository, Gradle looks for all versions there as well.
3. Make sure your Gradle cache is fast (think local SSD vs NFS mounted old disk). Otherwise move your $GRADLE_USER_HOME to another local place.
4. Adding DependencyResolutionListener may give you more information regarding what may be the bottleneck.

Try adding the following to the start of your build.gradle:

```
gradle.addListener(new DependencyResolutionListener() {
    ThreadLocal<Long> start = new ThreadLocal<>()
    @Override
    void beforeResolve(ResolvableDependencies dependencies) {
        start.set(System.nanoTime())
    }

    @Override
    void afterResolve(ResolvableDependencies dependencies) {
        long stop  = System.nanoTime() - start.get()
        println "resolving $dependencies.resolutionResult.root.moduleVersion of configuration $dependencies.name (${stop/1000000} ms)"
    }
})
```

Comment: Let me start off today by saying how much I appreciate the help of the community.  As it turns out we are already on local SSDs. RAM disk might be an option but profiling shows that dependency resolution is one of, if not THE, bottlenecks. Total task execution: 11m46.27s  All dependencies: 22m17.52s Configuration: 3.168s. I'll be looking at this some more today. If we can't get it faster than Maven's 6 minutes with clean and rules build, this migration may be canceled.

Comment: And you have only defined one repository to get artefacts from?

Comment: That's actually a very good point @Joachim Nilsson.  I do have repos scattered about.

Comment: Try replacing them all with one proxy. That will do the trick for you.

Comment: Keep in mind that I was running with --offline so this shouldn't have been an issue.

Comment: Ah, true. Then it IS strange. Can you post the profiling result as part of your question?

Comment: We are making extensive use of dependency lists to replace Maven BOM's. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Upgrading definitely seems to have improved matters.  Before I was building at 14 minutes at best without a clean and offline. Now I'm at 11minutes with a clean and online. Note that --parallel now seems to work whereas it seemed to have a beef with ant.xjc before. Going to keep at it. Still need to get below 6 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried adding the DependencyResolutionListener according to the link you found? That would be interesting to follow I suppose.

Comment: Negative. No details are given regarding when, where or how to attach an instance of that Interface. Does it go in the base project or the problem child project? Etc. etc. etc. Right now I'm having problems with dependency resolution in ant xjc jaxb tasks but IMHO the answer to any ant question is: Step 1: Get rid of Ant.

Comment: Adding example to the answer

Comment: I have this licked. :-) :-) :-)  I was using Gradle 2.8 and I upgraded to 2.11. That helped a great deal. Also I moved everything I could out of subprojects and allprojects. This also helped. I also had to replace my ant xjc tasks with a JavaExec that does the same thing as Ant kept dropping dead on me when using --parallel.  Current build time is 1 min 14 seconds! :-) Further I started using the gradle wrapper.

Comment: Actually we didn't have it licked. Shortly thereafter we ran into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577640/why-is-gradle-excluding-required-dependencies Our solution was to use the Nebula plug-in and change the packaging on all the BOMs to jar. Now that means we have empty JAR files but it was not as bad as the alternative.  I don't recommend the Spring plug-in. Based on our experiences, it doesn't scale well.