# Why is Gradle excluding required dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, dependencies

Environment: Linux, Artifactory, Java web apps, Gradle 2.12 with Spring dependency management plug-in and Flyway plug-in.

We are NOT using the Artifactory plug-in. We are just hitting it as if it were a generic maven repository.

Project is massive with something between 80 and 90 sub-projects. We have had several people working on migrating it over from Maven but there have been many headaches. We've beaten most of them but this particular series of knots is very close to sinking us.

Problems:

1. The build is not faster than Maven using `--daemon` and not `--parallel`. This seems pretty weird. Profiling shows that dependency resolution is taking a very long time.
2. Some aspect of the build is not stable. This is to say that we get various compiler issues when we try to build. This happens regardless of whether we use `--parallel` or not, although it happens to a greater degree with `--parallel`. It also happens regardless of local or remote dependencies. We suspect that it is related to some aspect of dependency resolution or perhaps as a result of unexpected exclusion behavior on the part of Gradle. Specifically, we get "Class def not found" and / or "missing symbol". Usually this seems to be related to a transitive dependency. If I put it in explicitly, the error goes away and I get a new one pertaining to a different transitive. I've experimented with putting them in as both transitive and as `transitive = false`.
3. Complicating matters, we have many BOMs. Perhaps 10? Some are ours and others belong to 3rd parties. Two or three are more than a page in length.

Without `--parallel` we can't seem to get the performance we need to justify the migration but we could, perhaps, survive that and wait for `--parallel` to finish incubating *IF* we could get it to build reliably. We've been cycling on `--debug` for about 2 weeks now but our shop is, naturally, inexperienced with Groovy and Gradle.

Clarification: It works about 30% of the time with `--parallel` and about 90% of the time without. If you build the specific project in question, using the full project path or changing to that sub-directory, there is no problem building.

From the `--debug` output, for example, I see:

```
...
-classpath 
/development/.../build/classes/main
/development/.../build/resources/main
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.7.RELEASE/8c6c02bcccfa23a74db59f7b7725e69e1af38f04/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
/development/.../build/libs/data-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.18.Final/2b4c72104fe1910d368d766243f0d0ac2608e134/hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/joda-time/joda-time/2.8.1/f5bfc718c95a7b1d3c371bb02a188a4df18361a9/joda-time-2.8.1.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/ce1edb914c94ebc388f086c6827e8bdeec71ac2/commons-lang-2.6.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-orgmanagement-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-stuffmanagement-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.pnq/pnq-someutils/6.7.0-SNAPSHOT/642a90ae7cc4f3f9b281184cacbfa1294f176df8/pnq-someutils-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.eaio.stringsearch/stringsearch/2/44618501b2fb6b2d1bb851d00b264a6eaf1fc0b0/stringsearch-2.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.52/88a941faf9819d371e3174b5ed56a3f3f7d73269/bcprov-jdk15on-1.52.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/761ea405b9b37ced573d2df0d1e3a4e0f9edc668/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/4b95f4897fa13f2cd904aee711aeafc0c5295cd8/commons-codec-1.10.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.1.7.RELEASE/e52148e9671e2918a2172c9cf56b77bede2042ce/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.4.1/2231238e391057a53f92bde5bbc588622c1956c3/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.1.7.RELEASE/d8923bdffe631904899875e719d8b363bc3deaea/spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javolution/javolution-core-java/6.2.0rc3/5bae18008a0182d80155dbbe2c91d8907d2496d/javolution-core-java-6.2.0rc3.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.1.7.RELEASE/3465a5d3b24006d51482cf45abd13e347f64582a/spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/6f3b8a24bf970f17289b234284c94f43eb42f0e4/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.pnq/pnq-batchutils/6.7.0.2/9c025552239645478a759267748c73f3e1e43a47/pnq-batchutils-6.7.0.2.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-mailutils-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.pnq/pnq-utilities/6.7.0.2/d1e8ad707ebd2eddbb29eb0052c05b34acd98b46/pnq-utilities-6.7.0.2.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-database-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.twilio.sdk/twilio-java-sdk/3.3.9/133f7bde99aefae1df78ecd9787e5e60bc521ad2/twilio-java-sdk-3.3.9.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7/2ceb567b8f3f21118ecdec129fe1271dbc09aa7a/velocity-1.7.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.mail/mail/1.4.1/8b7bc69010655425dabf091b51d1e90b4de36715/mail-1.4.1.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5/a1e6cbb3cc2c5f210dd1310ff9fcb2c09c0d1438/httpclient-4.5.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-infoassembler-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-stufflookup-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/someUser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.pnq/pnq-rcrtrlss/6.7.0-SNAPSHOT/58d6caa20da9035ce7b311f54915448c5bb903dc/pnq-wierdorules-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-cmanagement-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-translation-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-eutilities-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/development/.../build/libs/pnq-control-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/development/../database/build/libs/test-pnq-database-6.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
...
    14:50:06.439 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] junit:junit is excluded from com.project:project-enterprise-test:6.7.0.2(default).
    ...
        st.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
        14:50:06.481 [ERROR] [system.err] import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
        14:50:06.481 [ERROR] [system.err]                        ^
```

Note: A global search shows there are NO excludes for `junit` anywhere in the Gradle build. Also, what *DON'T* I see in the `-classpath`? Junit. 
...but in the relevant `build.gradle` file I see:

```
testCompile ("com.project:project-enterprise-test")
```

The above is a BOM containing Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
      <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>cglib</groupId>
          <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fitnesse</groupId>
      <artifactId>fitlibrary</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.dbfit</groupId>
      <artifactId>dbfit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.servicefixture</groupId>
      <artifactId>servicefixture</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

In the root `build.gradle`:

```
dependencyManagement {
    ...
    imports {
      mavenBom "com.project:project-enterprise-test:$bomversion"
    }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to migrate everything at once, or are you doing it one subproject at a time?  Also, what specific failures are you getting in your builds?

Comment: Big bang. We started with the init tool.

Comment: You have to have decoupled projects to get parallel execution and configuration on demand working properly. Besides that, the speed is not the only reason why Gradle is better than Maven. There is power, flexibility, readability, ..... and much more. And also the speed gain is mainly due to Gradles excellent UP-TO-DATE checkes, so the initial build may not be faster, but successive builds should be. At least if you configure your tasks inputs and outputs correctly and even more if then the daemon is used.

Comment: The Gradle Guide defined "decoupled" as not having much of anything in allProjects and subProjects at the root. I've already moved everything possible out of there. The only things remaining are plug-ins. Spring Dependency management, the Java plugin goes in there and our repositories.

Comment: Speed isn't the only reason but it is the best reason. It translates directly to the team's bottom line which makes Gradle much easier to sell to Management so that developers can reap the rewards of the other reasons. ...also as noted we already are using the daemon and yet for some reason we are as slow as Maven. There is one thing that might be an issue. We have bi-directional build dependencies between test and integrationTest. Something I've been trying to get a mandate to fix for some time now. Unit tests should never depend on integrationTest.

Comment: I think we are stuck with the Spring dependency management plug-in or we have to figure out a new way to deal with BOM's. Version management could be done with properties. We've already considered the Netflix series of plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to help you if you don't include

- related `build.gradle` snippets
- the actual errors

For the dependency version mismatches, I suggest that you compare
`mvn dependency:tree` against `gradle dependencyInsight` to see what's different.

Maven and Gradle have different ways of dealing with multiple versions of the same dependency within the dependency hierarchy.

- Maven uses a "nearest definition wins" strategy.
- By default, Gradle will choose the latest version (or you can also define a custom [ResolutionStrateegy](http://pkaq.github.io/gradledoc/docs/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html))

Comment: We did that. No difference. ,,,well not exactly. They were different but all the dependencies were present. The war files build fine with the exception of the instability.

Comment: Our approach was to get the two builds as close as possible first, and then fix any errors. They were as identical as we could make them before we started trying to cope with these issues. Doesn't mean we didn't hose something up but we did our level best not to.  We know about resolution strategies and how to force a dependency when Gradle doesn't match Maven.

Comment: You say "all the dependencies were present" but are they the same versions?

Comment: Dependency management ensures that this is the case. There were a few strays, i.e. transitive dependencies not mentioned in dependency management that Gradle was upgrading but we handled those by enforcing the Maven version.